# iptables for forwarding VLAN does not work as expected

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a VLAN interface wlp2s0.10, created by the following commands.

```
$ sudo ip link add link wlp2s0 name wlp2s0.10 type vlan id 10
$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev wlp2s0.10
$ sudo ip link set up wlp2s0.10
```

And I configured a simple nginx server that host php files, listen on 10.0.0.1:8099. (`listen 10.0.0.1:8099;`)

So `curl -I 10.0.0.1:8099` does work now while `curl -I localhost:8099` does not work.

Now I want to access to the page from the internet over the machine's global IP 220.xx.xx.xx, with whitelisting my client IP 45.14.yy.yy.
So I tried following iptables commands:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i wlp2s0.10 --dport 8099 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:8099
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 10.0.0.1 --dport 8099 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlp2s0.10 -p tcp --dport 8099 -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlp2s0.10 -p tcp --dport 8099 -d 10.0.0.1 -s 45.14.yy.yy -j ACCEPT
```

So now let's test that works by `curl -I 220.xx.xx.xx:8099` on my machine (IP: 45.14.yy.yy),
this should succeed. But it doesn't. (no server response)

So, where's wrong with the iptables commands?

Comment: Your IPTables command imply that you’re trying to set up a port forwarding on the same machine that is running the service. Why? This is simply a case of incoming TCP traffic, no routing or forwarding involved.

Comment: Also, iptables is for **filtering** (and maybe doing the NAT; you didn't describe your network topology, and what is on the two subnets, and where the machines with the global IPs are, so it's not clear if the NAT is needed). You enable **forwarding** with `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` (or an equivalent way of setting that on boot). Without NAT and filtering, no iptables is needed in that case (and it's a pet peeve of mine that people confuse routing and forwarding with using iptables, because many tutorials don't make a clear distinction).

Comment: So what a working commands should like be? I also tried no portforwarding way `sudo iptables -I INPUT -i wlp2s0.10 -p tcp --dport 8099 -d 10.0.0.1 -s 45.14.yy.yy -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -i wlp2s0.10 -p tcp --dport 8099 -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP`, but this also didn't work, so I thought I needed nat portforwarding.

Comment: I alraedy have set up forwarding the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` stuff. I can apply the same above commands to my localhost (192.168.0.167) > a local network address (192.168.0.110) connection and it's working.

Comment: umm sorry I don't quite grasp what you say. do you mean I don't need to use iptables for this? if so what I can use? what info I need to add on the post?

Comment: You'd better put a schematic of your setup, or else add this (in the question, not in comments) once your system is configured: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` and `iptables-save -c`.